# Why following code shows setVideoSource failed exception

Tags: android

```
 MediaRecorder mr=new MediaRecorder();   
 mr.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you first try adding a couple uses-permissions to you AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```