# A strange issue: "setVideoSouce failed"

Tags: android

I am working on a app about recording videos, but I have problems using the app. When I click the record button, it stops. I have already checked the logcat, it said "setVideoSource failed." :(
By the way, I am not really good at English, I may make some mistakes... QAQ
And here is my code:

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
    recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setVideoFrameRate(25);
    recorder.setVideoSize(800,480);
    recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    recorder.setOutputFile(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Android Emulator, the Emulator camera is maybe set up wrong.
***[More infos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37390717/7015204)***

Or you don't have the ***[the right permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8103048/7015204)***.

Comment: I am using Xiaomi Redmi 4A, and I have added these permissions:</br><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" /></br>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/></br>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>

Comment: What Android version are you running?